# Geb test ignoring GebConfig.groovy file while launched in Eclipse

Tags: groovy, geb

I am new to geb, need help in configuring the gebconfig file.

**Issue:**
Not able to created report dir thru geb config file.

1.I have kept GebConfig.groovy  in /src/test/resources. But while execution, its not taking the values from config file.

2. Also i tried keeping GebConfig.groovy in src/{default package}, still same issue.

**Script File:**
reportsDir="target/geb-reports"

**Error Message:**
No reports dir has been configured, you need to set in the config file or via the build adapter.

Note: Running in Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Try putting `GebConfig.groovy` into `src/test/groovy`. Please also try to add log statements to the file such as `println "Geb config file was loaded"`. Editing the question in order to include the actual file content would also be helpful, maybe someone can spot bugs there. It is kind of counter-productive to ask questions about the very thing you are hiding from us here. Maybe you want to learn how to ask questions in [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) format.

Comment: Hi kriegaex, Thanks for the inputs.  By adding the folder as source folder in Buildpath solves the issue.

Comment: Yeah, it is always a good idea to add the source folder to the list of source folders. 